# build json data from php object

Tags: php, json

I want to buld a Json object to feed my graphs. I have got the following code to change my PHP object.

```
    $rows = $this->Website_model->getGraphData();       

    $_rows = array();

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
            $_rows[$i][] = $value;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $rows = $_rows; 


    echo json_encode(array("sEcho" => intval($sEcho), "data" => $rows));
    die();
```

My current ouput looks like this:

```
array(24) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "3283581"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2013-10-16"
  }
```

It should look something like this:

```
{"y":15,"x":"2012-11-19"},{"y":18,"x":"2012-11-19"} etc etc
```

How can I add the Y and X to my data and take care i will get the right output to feed my graph?

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I tried the following:

Now i'm using the following code:

```
    $rows = $this->Website_model->getGraphDataPositives();      

    $_rows = array();

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
            $_rows[$i]['x'] = $value;
            $_rows[$i]['y'] = $value;
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

This results in the following response:

```
array(48) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["x"]=>
    string(7) "3283581"
    ["y"]=>
    string(7) "3283581"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["x"]=>
    string(10) "2013-10-16"
    ["y"]=>
    string(10) "2013-10-16"
  }
```

So it isn't okay yet.. it should say:

```
array(48) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["x"]=>
    string(7) "3283581"
    ["y"]=>
    string(7) "2013-10-16"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["x"]=>
    string(10) "1512116"
    ["y"]=>
    string(10) "2013-10-17"
  }
```

Comment: are you sure that is your current output ?

Comment: From your code and question it's quite difficult to understand what it is that you're trying to achieve. Please clarify.

Comment: the current output is the output i'm getting as an answer in my Firebux console as answer from the GET Request.

Comment: @Kleskowy I'm trying to achieve is to have the data in a format like my last examle to put this in a javascript variable called qm.graphData. This will be loaded my the xgrap on my site. The data is coming from my controller (in a codeigniter MVC structure)

Answer (score 0):

This would create an array like you wish :

```
$rows = $this->Website_model->getGraphData(); 
$_rows = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    $_rows[$i]['y'] = $rows[0];
    $_rows[$i]['x'] = $rows[1];
    $i++;
}
```

Your example data is not correct. You have array(3), but you show only 2 elements. Also in the output data you have 3283581 and the y values are 15 and 18. So there is no way I can guess how to convert those values.

Comment: i wasn't that clear i think.. the output should be {"y":3283581,"x":"2013-10-16"}  etc... the array should contain 2 not 3 :)

Comment: // I'm getting the following error with this solution 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in //apps.php on line 64

Comment: Line 64 is: $_rows[$i]['y'] = $row[0];

Comment: This means that row is an object, not an array like you show in your example data. There's no way for me to guess what are the members of your object to write the code.

Comment: What I need to help you is a var_dump of $rows before the foreach loop.